# C# and ASP.NET Core Identity: performance improving GetUserAsync calls

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC project written in C# and using ASP.NET Core Identity.

I have a controller with multiple actions for reading/writing from the database, where the query relies on having the `ApplicationUser.Id` value for every request.

How can I circumvent having to continuously call the following method to look up the current `ApplicationUser` and obtain their `Id`?

```
protected async Task<ApplicationUser> GetCurrentApplicationUser()
{
    var httpContextUser = HttpContext.User;
        
    return await _userManager.GetUserAsync(httpContextUser);
}
```

I am looking at this purely from a performance perspective.

Comment: `var userId = HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach. This works because `_applicationUserTask` only executes once but can be awaited multiple times. That means it won't execute over and over.

I didn't include it, but you could define an interface like `IApplicationUserAccessor`. Or you could just register this class directly with the DI container. It depends on whether you want to inject an interface or a concrete class into your controller.

What's important is that this must be registered as scoped.

```cs
services.AddScoped<ApplicationUserAccessor>();
```

...to ensure that there's a new instance for every request.

```cs
public class ApplicationUserAccessor
{
    private readonly Task<ApplicationUser> _applicationUserTask;

    public ApplicationUserAccessor(
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, 
        IUserManager userManager)
    {
        _applicationUserTask = GetUserAsync(httpContextAccessor, userManager);
    }

    public async Task<ApplicationUser> GetCurrentApplicationUser()
    {
        return await _applicationUserTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private static async Task<ApplicationUser> GetUserAsync(
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
        IUserManager userManager)

    {
        HttpContext httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        ClaimsPrincipal httpContextUser = httpContext?.User;
        if (httpContextUser == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return await userManager.GetApplicationUser(httpContextUser);
    }
}
```

You could also combine this with caching. You could inject a longer-lived cache instance into this class.

Comment: This is excellent, many thanks. I have a distributed Redis cache that mirrors the database as the website has to deal with heavy traffic. Thanks for providing such a useful answer! I shall investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

You should use caching it can be in-memory cache or distributed caching (like redis or any other).

Just store the `ApplicationUser` in the cache and retrieve it easily.

Another option is to set user id in claimn, and search it within the `User.Claims` object.